# Perl Catalyst and FastCgi error logging issues

Tags: perl, apache, model-view-controller, fastcgi, catalyst

I have a catalyst app running through fast cgi and the apache error logs are useless.

Example:

```
[Thu Oct 13 08:44:35 2011] [error] [client {IP}] FastCGI: server "/usr/local/www/handprints2/script/handprints2_fastcgi.pl" stderr: |  -> handprints2::View::json->process                       | 0.000523s |, referer: https://[SERVER]/handprints2/

[Thu Oct 13 08:44:35 2011] [error] [client {IP}] FastCGI: server "/usr/local/www/handprints2/script/handprints2_fastcgi.pl" stderr: | /end                                                       | 0.000324s |, referer: https://[SERVER]handprints2/

[Thu Oct 13 08:44:35 2011] [error] [client {IP}] FastCGI: server "/usr/local/www/handprints2/script/handprints2_fastcgi.pl" stderr: '------------------------------------------------------------+-----------', referer: https://[SERVER]/handprints2/
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Not sure why I get a -1 for this. I added a few more log entries to the question. I know this is a common issue for Catalyst users but I cant find a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your own log feeds and format in apache using the `TransferLog` and `LogFormat` directives:

```
   TransferLog /tmp/sample.log
    LogFormat "bazinga -> %U"
```

See [Apache 2.0 Logging Directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#transferlog) or [Apache 1.3 Logging Directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#common)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and didn't really find the Apache log config route that convenient.

This does the job pretty well though: https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::Log::Handler

Description from CPAN:

> If your Catalyst project logs many messages, logging via standard
>   error to Apache's error log is not very clean: The log messages are
>   mixed with other web applications' noise; and especially if you use
>   mod_fastcgi, every line will be prepended with a long prefix.
>
> An alternative is logging to a file. But then you have to make sure
>   that multiple processes won't corrupt the log file. The module
>   Log::Handler by Jonny Schulz does exactly this, because it supports
>   message-wise flocking.
>
> This module is a wrapper for said Log::Handler.